# Git - Howto mix together two repositories

Tags: git, deployment

We want to deploy a CMS via GIT. The reason, why we want to do this, is out of the scope of the question. What we want to do can be seen in the picture below.

The system consists of a lot of files and a database. If we initially deploy a system, the current version of the development database should be deployed together with the system (right half of the Diamond).

While the system is in use, the users change the database, so we will never overwrite the database with new versions.

The other files might be updated via GIT (left half of the Diamond). If we put the database into the same branch, it would overwrite the database of the user, which is not, what we want. Therefore it should be in a separate branch or repo.

Given the files in the master branch and the database in the db branch (which contains all files, too) we initially checkout the db branch. In order to update the files we switch to the master branch, pull the files and then switch back to the db branch and merge the files from master.

The disadvantage is, that the database will be deleted for a short time. This has some implications, we don't want to cope with.

Is there any way we can deploy the whole system together with the db and then update only the files without switching to the other branch and back to the master, so that the database doesn't need to be deleted by Git?

I would be glad for any idea.

[Git Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzgv8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I can place the database in a db branch. The branch contains all files from master plus the database.

I get a clone of the newest system with

```
git clone http://host/myrepo.git mydir
cd mydir
git checkout db
```

I get the newest files without touching the database with

```
git pull origin master
```

"origin" ist the name of a so called "remote". This will be defined automatically after checkout and is kind of a shortcut for the URL of the repository. The line says something like:

Fetch the branch "master" from the repository at the url which is defined by the "original" remote definition. Merge the fetch results to the current working copy.